# Magento: show stock levels for specific date

Tags: magento, reporting, stock

I need a list of the stock levels of all products, per store, for a specific date in the past. Is there a way to go back and see how many items were in stock for product X, and then for all products?

Comment: check this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/175930/#t222434

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, no. There is no history of the stock, or any "snapshots" of the product stock at any time.
What you can do, but this is not 100% reliable since the stock can be altered manually, is to get the current stock and subtract from it the quantity ordered since the day you want until now. To get the qty ordered for a product you can use one of the [methods described here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/175930/#t222434). All of them use the sales reports models to retrieve data.
Or you can try [this one](http://magentofresher.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/magento-get-total-quantity-of-product-sold/), but you need to add the date filters by yourself.